# Return last inserted record with greenDAO

Tags: android, greendao

I am developing an android App with greenDAO, I need to insert an order-detail but I dont't find a practical way to do it, I don't know if there is a method that returns the created object.

```
order.setCantidad(cant)
orderDao.insert(order)
int lastReg = getLastReg(); // this return the last recort inserted
detail.setOrderId(lastReg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi it depends on the structure of your rows and table.
if you make use of key do this

```
List<Order> orders = orderDao.queryBuilder()
  .orderAsc(Properties.Id)
  .limit(1)
  .list()
```

lastOrder = orders[0]